# Conditional count in filtered range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet with about a million rows. Within one particular column, I have numbers ranging from `0` to `50,000`.

**I am trying to determine, within a filtered range, how many cells in the filtered range fall within a certain value.**

I can easily do a `=COUNTIF(L:L, "<5000")` to see how many rows are less than 5,000, or `=COUNTIFS(L:L,">500",L:L,"<5000")` to see numbers in the TOTAL range that fall between two numbers, but I cannot figure out how to do either of these *in a filtered range*.

Normally with filtered data I use the `=SUBTOTAL` function, but I cannot see how any of the established `=SUBTOTAL` functions would work in this example.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for a formula or a piece of VBA code?

Comment: formula right now - eventually I'll put it into VBA.  - oh, my bad - I didn't realize I tagged this as VBA...  Either one would be fine actually....  It's eventually going to end up in a macro once I work it all out anyway...

Comment: Rows have a '.hidden' property (ex 'rows(3).hidden') that you can use to determine if a filter has hidden a row or not. I would just walk through every row, counting if it meets your criteria and if it is not hidden. This is for VBA, if you are going to use that. Not sure about an excel formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution. I have commented the code so you shouldn't have any problem understanding it but if you do then simply post back.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, n As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rngArea As Range

    '~~> Change this as applicable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Finding last row in Col L
        lRow = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

        'Debug.Print Intersect( _
                              .Range("L2:L" & lRow), _
                              .Range("L1").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                              ).Address

        '~~> This is your range of all visible cells till the last row in column L
        '~~> except the header:
        Set rng = Intersect( _
                              .Range("L2:L" & lRow), _
                              .Range("L1").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                              )

        '~~> Since the area could be non contiguous we use Countif per area and add up
        For Each rngArea In rng
            n = n + Application.Evaluate("=COUNTIFS(" & rngArea.Address & _
                                         ","">500""," & rngArea.Address & ",""<5000"")")
        Next

        Debug.Print n
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is really nice - I love how you solved this.  Thank you so much for the efforts!  I'm totally stealing your fancy `'~~>' for comments too....  much nicer than the standard VBA comment :)

Comment: `I'm totally stealing your fancy '~~>' for comments too....` NOOOO :D You may use `'-->` though ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this has happened to everyone, but after reading posts on this topic for like 30 minutes and not finding anything, I posted on SO, only to find a solution like 4 minutes later.......

This solution is for data that's in column L, where the criteria that I'm searching for is "under 5000"

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(L7,ROW(L7:L999999)-ROW(L7),,1)),--(L7:L999999 < 5000))
```