# excel vba autofilter range and delete all rows with 0 in col D

Tags: excel, filtering, delete-row, vba

I have a long list of data (product labels), another sheet has the raw data and calculations. I have a macro that imports the data in A2 - AP2. It scans Col D and deletes any row that has a zero (0) value in col D. I have it working but, is there some way to change the code to only delete the row from A to AP? I have 3 other codes that need this but I cant just delete an entire row due to other data / helper columns?

```
Worksheets("Labels").Activate
 ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

 ActiveSheet.Range(drop2).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=-", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=+"

    Dim oRow As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRows As Range
    With Sheets("Labels")
        Set myRows = Intersect(.Range("D:D").EntireRow, .UsedRange)
        If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    End With

    For Each oRow In myRows.Columns(1).Cells
        If oRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = oRow
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, oRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete

 ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Use `Intersect` with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` as shown [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828796/conditional-count-in-filtered-range/32829293#32829293) to work only with the filtered range :)

Comment: I will give It a shot Siddharth, I got most of my code (including the intersect) form a google search and another forum. to be honest I'm not 100% sure what the code is doing, but it does work for the most part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't guess what your doing in the code without seeing your excel data. But, based on what you explained, you will look through column D and if you find 0 then you will delete the entire row. But, you don't want to delete the entire row as that will delete the helper column. I am just trying to repeat what you said. If this is what you want, use range Delete function call with Shift:=xlUp

```
Range("A2:AP2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

This will not delete the entire row, but will only delete data in A2:AP2 and shift all the below cells up. Kind of deleting your entire row and leaving your helper columns untouched.

**Update 1:**

I will try to explain it with a small example. Below screenshot shows the sample data I am using,

[image]

The yellow marked cells have zero values and the entire rows need to be cleared out except the helper column data. Below is the sample code for this excel data,

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim myRows As Range

Set myRows = Intersect(Sheet1.Range("A:E").EntireRow, Sheet1.UsedRange)
If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For i = 1 To myRows.Rows.Count
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 4) = 0 Then
        Sheet1.Range("A" & CStr(i) & ":E" & CStr(i)).Delete (xlUp)
    End If
Next
```

If the above code gets executed, below is the screenshot of the result. Note that the entire row of column D with 0 value got deleted leaving Helper columns unaffected.

[image]

Comment: it wont always be row 2, as it will scan from row 2 until X ( usually less than 5000). Should I set the current row its looking checking to a variable ex        Range("A2:AP2").Delete Shift:=xlUp would be dim rd as string dr = activecell.row  Range("A" & rdel &":AP" & rdel).Delete Shift:=xlUp

Comment: Yes. that was an example I tried to put. definitely you will have to use it dynamically. "If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete" - this is in your code, probably, you may need to call rng.Delete Shift:xlUp. Something like that.

Comment: `Dim rdel As String       If Not rng Is Nothing Then Range("A" & rdel & ":AP" & rdel).Delete shift:=xlUp` deleted all my data, good thing I saved a version before trying this. I am guessing I incorrectly coded something.

Comment: Good you got a copy of it. Always do testing of code in a separate copy leaving the original safe. I have updated the answer with a sample and screenshots. Please check if it can help on your problem.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed . If i wanted this to insert a row do I need to change the `.delete` to `.insert xldown`  in that last lint of code?

Comment: Thats true, if you want to insert a row call .insert. Eg: Sheet1.Range("A2:E2").Insert(xlDown) will insert a row of cells on second row from A to E.